# How i can get response from $resource POST request

Tags: angularjs

So looks my request:

```
angular.module('todoApp').factory('UsersService', ['$resource', 'paramsService', '$q', function($resource, paramsService, $q){
var server = paramsService.serverUrl;
return {
    'auth': function(username, password){
        var $response = {};
        $resource(server + '/api/account/auth', {}, {call: {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}}).call(
            {'username': username, 'password': password},
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $response = data;
            }
        );
        console.log($response);
        return $response;
     },
  }
}]);
```

At success function i hava response in data, but variable $response is empty. I know but why it happens, but can't find way to wait response to return it. How can i get response from $resource?

Comment: look at example in tutorial on docs.angularjs site. Scope items accept promise

Answer (score 0):

As charliefl commented you need to use the promise object returned from the $resource request to await the completion of the function ($resource is asynchronous).

My PHP code for handling the POST request returned the number of bytes written to the file.  I parsed that back from the response using the code below.  Since the 'resource' object was not a true array (like 'arguments') I had to loop through possible indices until one returned 'undefined'.

So the bottom line is whatever is in your response body will be returned to you as an array of bytes on the resource object.

```
$resource(...POST REQUEST...)
        .$promise.then(function (resource) {
            var bytesSaved = '';
            var i = 0;
            while (resource[i] !== undefined) {
                bytesSaved += resource[i];
                i++;
            }
            $scope.lessonMsg = 'File saved, ' + bytesSaved + ' bytes'
        }
        function(error) {
            $scope.msg = 'An error occurred trying to save the file. ' + error;
        }
    );
```

Here is the PHP code generating the POST response:

```
case "POST":
    $params = explode("file/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $filename = '../common/resources/fileContents' .  $params[1] . '.json';
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),false);
    $fileJson = file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($data));
    echo $fileJson;
break;
```

The file_put_contents() call returns the number of bytes written or false if there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello @falloff please try with below code snippet, I think this will work for you. Also, let me know whether It works or not.

```
angular.module('todoApp').factory('UsersService', ['$resource', 'paramsService', '$q', function($resource, paramsService, $q){
  var server = paramsService.serverUrl;
  return {
    'auth': function(username, password){
      let resource = $resource(server + '/api/account/auth', {}, {
        save: {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        },
      });
      resource.save(
        {'username': username, 'password': password}, (response) => {

          if (response.length !== 0 && response.length === 0) {
            // You will get respose here in 'response'
          }
          else {
            // If response is null
          }
          deferred.resolve('request successful');
        },
        (err) => {
          // Error
          deferred.reject(err);
        });
    },
  }
}]);
```