# Post data with by $resource authentication?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I got $http request that works fine

```
var data = {name: 'Bite'}
var headers = { 
    'Content-type': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization':localStorage.getItem('jwt_token')} 

$http.post('/cats/api/', data, {headers: headers})
.then(
    function(thing) {
        console.log(thing);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

And I want to use $resource for requests. I already made some simple requests with 'GET' method. But can't understand how to create request with 'POST' or 'PUT' data and authorization.

I tried many thongs like this:

```
var app = angular.module('Qwe', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('Catsfactory', ['$resource', '$window', 
    function($resource, $window) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8000/cats/api/', {},
            {
                create: {
                    method: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    isArray:false,
                    headers:{headers}  
                }      
            }
        )
}]);
app.controller('CatCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window','$resource', 'Catsfactory',
    function($scope, $http, $window,$resource, Catsfactory) {
        var qwe = Catsfactory.create(data);
        qwe.$promise
        .then(function(thing) {
            console.log(thing);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
}])
```

but that does not work out

Comment: Have you encountered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15927073/4636715

Comment: @vahdet yeah it answers back  huge response with HTML code and statusText: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: If `Internal Server Error` occurs, you'd better call your backend API with some tool like Postman. And once making sure it returns valid responses, you may then return to that client-side coding.

Comment: @vahdet I got perfect working $http request. Just can't figure out how to write a request through $resource. It is not a back-end bug. I am doing something wrong in the angular code.

Comment: You named the method `.create` but you are invoking the `.save` method. Also the property should be `headers` with an `s`.

Comment: @georgeawg yep I already fixed that and still can't request. This code is just an example. I already wasted 6 hours for $resource, simple requests, searching and tried many different things. Can use only .query() method for getting list of objects...